# Jqgrid conflicting with wordpress query vars

Tags: wordpress, jqgrid

I have written a wordpress plugin that uses jqgrid. When I submit one of the rows in the jqgrid to be saved, the names in my table columns (like "name") are conflicting with the wordpress query vars and causing a 404 to be returned.

Is there any way to get the jqgrid post to be wrapped in another object, so it's not posting the raw query var "name" to the server? Can it post something like

```
$_POST = array(
    'jqgrid' = array('oper' => 'add', 'name' => 'whatever')
);
```

instead of

```
$_POST = array('oper' => 'add', 'name' => 'whatever');
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid has [prmNames](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) option which can be used to rename any of the parameters used in URL or POST by jqGrid. For example default value for the "add" operation are defined by `addoper:"add"`.

I don't understand what you mean under the "name" parameter. the column name are not used as the name of any parameter which are posted. If you have the problem because of the usage of [toolbar searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching) I would recommend you to use `stringResult:true` option which makes information about the searching in the same format like in case of the usage of [advanced searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadvanced_searching). If you describe the problem more detailed I am sure that I could help you.

**UPDATED:** You can use [serializeEditData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) (for [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing)), [serializeRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#saverow) (for [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing)) or [serializeCellData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) (for [cell editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing)) to convert in any way the data which will be send to the server during Edit/Add operation.

Comment: "name" is one of the columns in my table. It's being sent to the server when I submit an edit or add on jqgrid, and then wordpress is picking that up and looking for a page with the name that is submitted along with 'name'. I cannot change the name of the column in my table to be anything other than "name".

Comment: @jessica: OK! Now I understand what you mean. In the case you can use  `serializeEditData` (for form editing), `serializeRowData` (for inline editing) or `serializeCellData` (for cell editing) to convert **in any way** the data which will be send to the server.